# OPNSense OpenVPN Site to Site VPN unable to reach internal networks

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, openvpn, opnsense

I've been pulling my hair out setting up a site to site vpn with OPNSense.
I followed the official guide with one exception, I'm using certificates.
And I saw in a video that the interfaces created by the server and client have to be enabled, which I did.
The VPN connection is established but I'm not able to ping anything from the server or client side. I'm just starting out with firewall rules so my apologies if this is something really simple that I don't understand yet.
I'd like to say thank you in advance for any help.

https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/sslvpn_s2s.html

More detail regarding the setup:

## Site A (Server):

### OpenVPN server config (legacy)

- Server Mode: Peer to Peer (SSL/TLS)
- Protocol:UDP4 Device Mode: tun
- Interface:WAN
- Local Port: 1194
- TLS Authentication: Disabled
- Peer Certificate Authority: local-ca
- Server Certificate: local-crt
- Encryption Alogorithm: AES-256-CBC
- Auth Digest Algorithm: SHA512
- IPv4 Tunnel Network: 10.10.100.0/24
- IPv4 Local Network: 192.168.0.0/24
- IPv4 Remote Network: 10.19.0.0/24
- Compression: Enabled LZ4 v2

### Interfaces:

- VPN interface: enabled

### Firewall Rules:

- WAN: Protocol UDP4 Allow any on Destination Port 1194 to Destination This Firewall
- OpenVPN: Protocol IPv4 Allow any (no changes/default config)

## Site B (Client)

### OpenVPN client config (legacy)

- Server Mode: Peer to Peer (SSL/TLS)
- Protocol:UDP4 Device Mode: tun
- Interface:WAN
- Remote server:

  - Host or Address: 1.2.3.4
  - Port: 1194
- TLS Authentication: Disabled
- Peer Certificate Authority: local-ca
- Server Certificate: local-crt
- Encryption Alogorithm: AES-256-CBC
- Auth Digest Algorithm: SHA512
- IPv4 Tunnel Network: 10.10.100.0/24
- IPv4 Remote Network: 192.168.0.0/24
- Compression: Enabled LZ4 v2

### Interfaces:

- VPN interface: enabled

### Firewall Rules:

- OpenVPN: Protocol IPv4 Source: 192.168.0.0/24 Allow any (no changes/default config)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.